# Check visitors Operating System in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Paul Silver had [this post](http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/coldfusion_detect_browser.php) 7 years ago to check various browsers.  Has there been an updated script since then?
What I'd like is an if/then construct to tell what Operating System the user is on - it doesn't have to go all the way down to the browser version.
I'm using the cgi.user_agent string to infer what OS they're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to detect what user agent is making the request.

On that line, you will see something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

And there is your operating system.

Hope it helps

**UPDATE:**

And just in case you're curious to know what the OS name is for the server hosting your application, you can simply use this:

```
<cfset system = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperties()>
<cfdump var="#system['os.name']#">
```